# Actionscript 3, JQuery SWF Object plugin and ExternalInterface problem

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, swfobject, externalinterface

I'm trying to write a simple flash mp3 player while using JQuery and it's SWF Object plugin.
I'm adding an swf to the page using this code:

```
$("body").append("<div id='player_external' style='position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:1px;width:1px;'></div>");
$('#player_external').flash({swf:"player_external.swf",wmode:"transparent",height:1,width:1,AllowScriptAccess:"always"});
```

The player should be invisible one-pixel object that interacts with javascript.
When i'm calling javascript functions from within flash objects (using `ExternalInterface.call()`) it works fine.

But when i try to call ActionScript function from JavaScript nothing happens.
I have added a callback function like this:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("MyFunc",MyFunc);
```

And I've tried all possible ways I've found on the internet. Like:

```
$('#player_external').context.MyFunc();
$('#player_external').flash("MyFunc()"); //this just crashes browser!
```

Also, the solution found here: [How can I call an Actionscript function when the .swf is referenced by jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473741/) doesn't help.
I gave up my hope on this. Maybe it's better to use flash without JQuery's help.
But there just should be some way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$('#player_external').get(0).MyFunc();`

Comment: No. That doesn't help. I think the problem may be because the div element is dynamically created, or because the swfobject doesn't add <embed> tag inside of an object (at least firebug shows it this way).

Comment: Ohhh! I think your comment just pointed it out. The exposed callback is a method of the object-element in the DOM. EDIT: Prematurely hit Enter. So, you have to make sure that you're operating on the *object-element* with your jQuery selector, and not on the div-element that SwfObject replaces.

Comment: I've tried many different ways to get object element, and i'm sure that i'm getting object element, not the div. But the function doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Just append an id paramter, so you can access the Flash object directly:

```
$('#my_container').flash({
    swf: 'swf/test.swf',
    width: 740,
    height: 110,
    wmode: 'transparent',
    allowScriptAccess:'always',
    id:'my_flash',
    flashvars: {}
});

// Use document.getElementById NOT $("#my_flash") 
document.getElementById("my_flash").myInternalFlashFuctionName('Foo');
```

Comment: I happened to find and read your answer. It solved my problem.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$('#myContent').get(0).method()` works for me. Using array reference to get the first item also works: `$('#myContent')[0].method()`

I'm using 'dynamic' swfobject injection.